# Failure to create Axis2 service in Eclipse WTP, Failure to create Axis2 service in Eclipse WTP, NoClassDefFoundError -CatalogManager

Tags: eclipse, apache-axis, eclipse-wtp

I am using Eclipse Galileo with Web tools platform and I am trying to create a sample Axis2 service.  I learned that Eclipse WTP does not work with Axis2 1.5, so I am using 1.4.1.  I mostly follow the following tutorial:

Eclipse WTP Tutorials - Creating Bottom Up Web Service via Apache Axis2 (http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html)
When I start tomcat built in Eclipse I am getting the following error:

[INFO] Exception creating Axis Service : null
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/resolver/CatalogManager
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1850)
    …..
[ERROR] Error:
 No annotated classes found in the jar: file:/C:/Users/narinskya/workspace5/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/axis2service/WEB-INF/servicejars/version.jar. Service deployment failed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like class loader is unable to load the CatalogManager class, which is in XML resolver jar file. Try to add XML resolver jar (xml-resolver-1.2.jar) to your WEB-INF/lib directory.